# IntelliJ git does not recognize changes in angular project files

Tags: git, intellij-idea-2016

I cloned a angular project from existing repository and I can see the folder under IntelliJ. But IntelliJ does not recognize any change in files. I can always commit from command line but its always good to see your changes in the IDE.
I tried creating a module out of this directory but that did not work.

How do I make sure IntelliJ git recognizes my angular project.
For my other repositories when I clone it, I add the pom.xml to maven build and that recognizes that its git project. But since my angular project does not have any pom how do I import the existing repository?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably opened your project from an invalid directory. You might want to double-check.For instance:

```
cd Desktop/project
git clone 'link here'
```

the above code may result in such a confusion.
`(user/Desktop/project or user/Desktop/project/project)`

Comment: I cloned the repository from command line to the correct folder. From command line it does recognize the changes but intelliJ is unable to do it. that is the problem. It won't show the changed files in different color. As if intelliJ is not recognizing the project as git project.